# Passing string to init function and storing it in a malloc'd struct

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

I am writing an init function to initializes the first node in a linked list. I am trying to add a string name to label each node but am getting weird behavior when the function returns. I am passing the string directly into the function, mallocing another char* of the same length then strcpy'ing the input string into this new location. I am trying to store it in a char** within the struct. It copies into the struct whilst within the init function but once it returns the string changes, which appears like the memory frees upon returning the init function.

```
typedef struct {
    key_grid_TypeDef* grid;

    char** name;
    uint8_t ID;

    void* next;
    void* prev;
} keymap_layer;

keymap_err_TypeDef keymap_init( keymap_list* layer_list,
    key_grid_TypeDef* grid, char* layer_name ){

//init initial layer
    keymap_layer *layer = (keymap_layer*) malloc (sizeof(keymap_layer));
    if (layer == NULL)
        return km_init_err;

    char* mal_name = (char*) 
    malloc((strlen(layer_name)+1)*sizeof(char));
    if (mal_name == NULL)
        return km_init_err;
    strcpy(mal_name,layer_name);
    layer->name = &mal_name;

    if(sizeof(keymap0) == sizeof(*layer->grid))
        memcpy(&layer->grid, &grid, KEYBOARD_ROWS * KEYBOARD_COLS);
    else{
        free(layer);
        return km_init_err;
}

return km_ok;}
```

in my task

```
ret = keymap_init(&key_layer_list, &keymap0, "Initial layer");
```

Thanks

Comment: "I am trying to store it in a char** within the struct" - why?

Comment: Please format properly your code snippet and provide all useful related definitions before posting

Comment: @molbdnilo so i can more easily change the string that it points to in the future.

Comment: *so i can more easily change the string that it points to in the future.* Now that needs an explanation.  How is changing a `char **` easier than changing a `char *`?

Comment: sorry i should of mentioned for me semantically it makes more sense @AndrewHenle

Comment: `layer->name = &mal_name;` makes more sense?  You're storing the address of a local variable.  That variable and its contents are lost when your function returns.  How does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly fishy:

```
char* mal_name = (char*) malloc((strlen(layer_name)+1)*sizeof(char));
if (mal_name == NULL)
    return km_init_err;
strcpy(mal_name,layer_name);
layer->name = &mal_name;
```

The local variable `mal_name` ceases to exist as soon as the `keymap_init` function terminates, so you are storing a pointer to that variable.

You should do this:

```
typedef struct {
    ...    
    char* name;   // just a simple pointer to char
    ...
} keymap_layer;

...
layer->name = malloc((strlen(layer_name)+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(layer->name, layer_name);
```

If you want to change the string stored in `layer->name` later, use `realloc`.

For example:

```
...
layer->name = realloc(layer->name, (strlen(new_name)+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(layer->name, new_name);
...
```

Disclamer: there is no error checking for brevity.

BTW: you don't cast the return value of `malloc`and `friends`.

Comment: Given `keymap_layer *layer = malloc (sizeof(keymap_layer));`, `layer->name = realloc(layer->name, (strlen(new_name)+1)*sizeof(char));` is highly likely to fail as `layer->name` won't be initialized.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I wrote _"If you want to change the string stored in layer->name **later**"_, meaning that is has been initialized previously.

Comment: @AlexHoffmann if this answer is useful, upvote it and/or click on the green checkmark, so that others will know that the answer was useful.